# How to apply first-child:first-letter to only one section?

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

please take a look [here](http://glamourina.pl).
I'd like to apply a different style to the first letters of all the blog posts that appear on the homepage.

I am trying with:
`p:first-child:first-letter {
color: violet;
font-size: 300%;
}`. It works almost fine. The problem is that it applies the style to ALL the `<p>` of the site.

I have also tried to apply a class to all the div containers, for example to `class="entry_blog"` and in CSS `p.entry_blog:first-child:first-letter', but these codes also don't work.

What am I doing wrong? How to apply the style to only the text inside `<div class="entry_blog" itemprop="articleBody">`?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
.entry_blog p:first-child:first-letter{color: viloet; font-size:300%;}
```

which call every 'p' in div.entry_blog instead of `p.entry_blog:first-child:first-letter` which call every 'p' with a class of 'entry_blog'

Answer (score 1):

```
.entry_blog p:first-child:first-letter,{ color:violet; font-size:300%; }
```

Was going to say that :)